# yadcf external filter dropdown always selected

Tags: jquery, datatables, yadcf

Im not able to figure this one out. Why are the dropdowns marked as blue after i select an item? Is this a bug? The dropdown is generated by yadcf which is a plugin for jquery datatables. Am i missing something?

Example code: http://plnkr.co/edit/kpQabGuM6HYRPiI1Av1E?p=preview

Example picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTXnF.jpg

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false
    });

    yadcf.init(table, [
        {
            column_number: 1,
            filter_type: "select",          
            filter_container_id: "ddl",
            filter_delay: 500,
            filter_reset_button_text: false,
            style_class:"form-control"          
        },
        {
            column_number: 2,
            filter_type: "select",
            filter_delay: 500,
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug, it's a feature!

As you can see inside of `jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css` file, there is a part;

```
.inuse, .ui-slider-range .inuse, .yadcf-filter-range-number-slider .inuse {
    background: #8BBEF0;
}
```

If you don't want this blue color, just override this with `white` color in your code.

```
<style>
.inuse, .ui-slider-range .inuse, .yadcf-filter-range-number-slider .inuse {
    background: #FFF;
}
</style>
```

You can see the working example here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vMO9bJHyAxx3inHyVB8V?p=preview)

Comment: A feature indeed, you better set it to `background: none;` that way you wont limit your UI to other possible colors around it...